# SQL c# insert Command doesn't work

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

I'm having a problem insertin data into my database.
I can read from the database by using the select query, so I know my connection string is correct, but for some reason the insert doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```
private string ConnectionString()
{
    return @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\dbBusiness.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
}
private void Insert()
{
   try{
        string sqlStrInsert = "INSERT INTO myTable ([param1],[param2])VALUES(@param1,@param2)";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString());
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlStrInsert, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
        command.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50);
        command.Parameters["@param1"].Value = numOf_company;
        command.Parameters["@param2"].Value = txt_name.Text;
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
      }
   catch(Exception ex)
      {
        throw new Exception(ex.ToString(), ex);
      }
}
```

It doesn't show any exeption, and when I check my table through the Visual studio explorer
nothing is added to the table.
Im having trouble figuring this out so
i'd appreciate anyone who helps

Comment: Please tell us how it doesn't work. Simply saying "it doesn't work" isn't **any where near** enough information to go on. Does it error? If so, with what? On what line?

Comment: What error message are you getting ?

Comment: use try/catch and debug see what exception do you get

Comment: Side-note: always use the `using` statement to ensure that unmanaged resources are disposed.

Comment: @user2139184: Hi, after change table to myTable, does it work?

Comment: I'v changed it but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you forgot your Initial Catalog in your connection. Because without it your code will try to run in master (the default database).
Here is a snippet that should help you, you will need to modify the code obviously for your benefit.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Working
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string DsQuery = "INSERT INTO table (param1,param2)VALUES(@param1,@param2)"; 
        string TgtServer = @".\SQLEXPRESS";
        DataSet dsServers = new DataSet();
        dsServers = ExecQuery(DsQuery, TgtServer, "InitialCatalog");
    }

    private static DataSet ExecQuery(string strQuery, string strServer, string strIC)
    {

        string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + strServer + ";Initial Catalog=" + strIC + ";Integrated Security=SSPI";
        string commandString = strQuery;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(commandString, connectionString);
            da.Fill(ds, "Table");
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An SQL Exception Occured: " + e.Message);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An General Exception Occured: " + e.Message);

        }

        return ds;

    }
}
```

}

Sorry I can't give you anything more but that is something I noticed was missing and based on the no error given I can't provide.

Here is further reading:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905872(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: What do I need to write in the initial catalog? Is it: |DataDirectory|\App_Data\dbBusiness.mdf or somthing else?

Comment: The name of the database you want to connect to.

Comment: Because this: "|DataDirectory|\App_Data\dbBusiness.mdf" is not a database that is a file holding all the records for a database. I cannot tell you what your database name is, out of all the information you have posted all I know is your server ".\SQLEXPRESS".

Comment: Where do I check what is my database name?

Comment: No problem, happy I could help, hopefully the code works as you need it to.

Comment: It would be cool to say how did you figure it out, so people after you could know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Who is TABLE!?!? The name of your table? If yes, please change this name because if a reserved keyword

```
INSERT INTO table (param1,param2)VALUES(@param1,@param2)
```

becomes (for example)

```
INSERT INTO myTable (param1,param2)VALUES(@param1,@param2)
```

Comment: i sure hope he just changed the names for the question

Comment: @King king: Yes, but is better not use this keyword

Comment: I did everything that was suggested, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @user2139184: Please post the error, have you changed the name of your table on DB?